# group dataframe using unique values of column as index

Tags: python, pandas

What is the most efficient way of group or stack the different values of dataframe indexing by value?

this df:

```
color   alert

blue    A
blue    B
red     A
green   C
```

to:

```
color   alert

blue    [A, B]
red     A
green   C
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need a [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and to aggregate into a `list`:

```
df.groupby('color').alert.agg(list).reset_index()

   color   alert
0   blue  [A, B]
1  green     [C]
2    red     [A]
```

Comment: To match expected output: `df.groupby('color')['alert'].agg(list).apply(lambda x: x if len(x)>1 else x[0]).reset_index()`

Comment: Yes @anky_91 I wouldn't recommend it though (even though its OPs output) :) Quite overkill, and can't imagine what benefit one could get from having such mixed dtypes